Should I use caulk for chimney counter-flashing with a kick bend?
We're in the process of installing 24-gauge galvanized steel counter-flashing for our brick chimney. The plan is to grind out about 1.5" of mortar with a 1/8" blade to make a kerf with a slight upward angle (for proper drainage), and then insert the counter-flashing with a kick bend (see the attached figure). In our tests, the flashing in this setup is firmly wedged into the kerf and does not require any additional adhesive to remain in place.
Our understanding is that caulk is used in this procedure (pre-filling the kerf prior to inserting the counter-flashing and/or as a bead to fill the kerf after inserting the counter-flashing) more for its adhesive properties than its sealing properties. Given that the kick bend creates such a strong mechanical bond between the counter-flashing and the masonry, is there any reason to use caulk in this application? It seems like it would only serve to prevent water from properly draining from the kerf. We're in Southern California, so we rarely, if ever, get freezing temperatures.
Alternatively, we could fill the kerf with mortar, which might have better drainage properties than caulk, but it's not clear to us what purpose it would actually serve.
Thank you for any advice you can offer!


Chimneys usually mean temps that can cause water freezing.  You want to prevent any water from getting into anything and freeze.  It might be rare, but possible certain weather conditions can drive water into that kerf and start freezing.  Cracking the mortar/chimney itself.

@crip659 thank you for your response! We have just clarified in the post that we're in Southern California so we rarely if ever get freezing temperatures - does that change your evaluation of the strategy? Thanks again :)
